# Парсинг XML в Grep

Tags: регулярные-выражения, windows, сеть, grep

В результате работы Masscan есть XML файл

`<host endtime="1480103894"><address addr="118.192.160.147" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="8000"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="104"/></port></ports></host>`

`<host endtime="1480103895"><address addr="39.177.186.8" addrtype="ipv4"/><ports><port protocol="tcp" portid="8000"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="45"/></port></ports></host>`

из которого нужны только IP в столбик. Сейчас я делаю это в Notepad++ (см. скриншот)[image: Notepad++]. Но хочется в Grep для Windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm). Подскажите как.

Comment: Вообще, в Windows лучше уж в Powershell распарсить XML и с помощью XPath `//address/@addr` получить нужные значения. В Notepad++ тоже можно использовать XSLT.

Comment: grep для этого не очень подходит. лучше awk или sed

Comment: `Ошибка: Попытка разобрать HTML с помощью регулярных выражений; система вернула Ктулху.` https://ruslanbes.com/blog/all/perevod-programmirovanie-otstoy/ . Может лучше для этого использовать что-нибудь типа `xml2`? Регулярки - не самый удобочитаемый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Прекрасно grep для этого подходит. Сам разобрался:

```
grep -E -o "([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([01]?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" file1 > file2
```

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<=address addr=")[^"]+'` - будет больше похоже на парсинг) Выбираем значение из поля addr